# Apply a function to every column of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have this:

```
df = DataFrame(dict(person= ['andy', 'rubin', 'ciara', 'jack'], 
     item = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'], 
     group= ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c1'], 
     age= [23, 24, 19, 49]))
df:

    age group item person
0   23  c1    a    andy
1   24  c2    b    rubin
2   19  c3    a    ciara
3   49  c1    c    jack
```

what I want to do, is to get the length of unique items in each column.
Now I know I can do something like:

```
len(df.person.unique())
```

for every column.

Is there a way to do this in one go for all columns?

I tried to do:

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(len(df.column.unique()))
```

but I know this is not right.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want [**`pd.Series.nunique`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html)

```
df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)

age       4
group     3
item      3
person    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Never thought I can do this.neat.

Comment: @xen.m.rph feel free to upvote now that you have 15 rep.  And the other answerers would appreciate an upvote as well since they put good effort in to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
for column in df:
    print(len(df[column].unique()))

4
3
3
4
```

Or:

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column].nunique())

4
3
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can the number of unique items in each column as:

```
for column in df.columns:
    print(len(df[column].unique()))
```

Comment: I'm new to python/pandas and this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

why not something like this,

```
df.nunique()
```